# Using AWS Cognito under the backend API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I wanted to check we can use a custom node.js implementation as wrapper for exposing the API's for identity and user management using aws cognito.

We already have a bunch of API's (on ASP.NET identity) and would not want to change anything in the downstream systems. We would like keep the API signatures and just move the implementation to node.js server for identity and user management

The current examples on awslabs and the documentation is mainly targeted for using this under a web/mobile applications. Is there any guideline/sample if we can use this as an API wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I'm misinterpreting the question, but are you just trying to use Cognito with node instead of on a web app? Are you asking about Cognito federated identities or Cognito user pools?

If federated identities, yes, that will be fine and you shouldn't have any issues. All of the APIs are available in the node SDK, and the general flow should be identical to any other non mobile flow.

If you're asking about user pools, it's a bit trickier. Authentication uses SRP to validate passwords, and the mobile/web SDKs do this for you. Outside of those, you'd have to implement it yourself, which is no fun at all. You could rip out the code that does it from any one of those SDKs (each are published on Github) to help with that. Alternatively, you could use admin no srp authentication, which carries the risk of sending the username/password over the wire but passes off the authentication to the Cognito server.